# Computing TTR on corpus

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, textacy

I'm trying to compute TTR of the Capitol Words corpus using lemmas over the entire vocabulary of each speaker.

I'm also trying to have `defaultdict` shuffle through each entry and then give a TTR percentage per each speaker. So far I have the code above, but not sure how to fix it so it works...

```
import nltk
cw = ReadCorpus(root)
from collections import defaultdict 
speaker_TTR = defaultdict(int)
for record in cw:
    total_words = set([])
    N = 0
    text = record['text']
    processed = nlp(text)
    textw = [t.lemma_ for t in processed]
    N += len(textw)
    total_words |= set(textw)
    V = len(total_types)
    TTR = float(V)/float(N)
    speaker_TTR[record['speaker_name']] += 1

print "V = ",V
print "N = ",N
print "TTR = ",TTR
```

Comment: The code is giving me values larger than one, but I need values lesser than one for TTR.

Comment: [Type-Token Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_density), in computational linguistics

Comment: Please show an example paragraph and example values of TTR. Also **make the code reproducible**, and add the missing imports.

Comment: You can rewrite this much more cleanly using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects)